# Neo4J - Node with multiple labels is a good practice?

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I am new to graph DB and using Neo4j for storing the data.
In my use case I am planning to multiple labels for nodes for easier fetch.
For e.g.

```
[MANUFACTURER, MANUFACTURER_CAR] -- MANUFACTURES --> [CAR {name:BWM}, MANUFACTURER_CAR] 
[MANUFACTURER, MANUFACTURER_CAR] -- MANUFACTURES --> [CAR {name:AUDI}, MANUFACTURER_CAR]
[MANUFACTURER, MANUFACTURER_BIKE] -- MANUFACTURES --> [BIKE {name:YAMAHA}, MANUFACTURER_BIKE]
[MANUFACTURER, MANUFACTURER_BIKE] -- MANUFACTURES --> [BIKE {name:BMW}, MANUFACTURER_BIKE]
```

For the `MANUFACTURER` node I put 2 labels named as `MANUFACTURER` and `MANUFACTURER_CAR` and similarly for `MANUFACTURER_BIKE` and so on...
On the other hand, for the BMW car instance I want use labels as `BMW` as well as `MANUFACTURE_CAR` so that I can back trace at any point in time.

Advantage what I see by this when I want to fetch BMW bike then I can write the query as `match (n:BMW:MANUFACTURER_BIKE) return n` instead of writing long and clustered query.

1. Is this practice is good and right approach to use multiple labels?
2. Also when I use `call db.schema()` in the browser I get very clumsy
   model because `MANUFACTURER`, `MANUFACTURER_BIKE` and `MANUFACTURER_CAR` are considered as separate
   node I guess.

Comment: 1. Labels for "things" should be nouns (e.g., `Manufacturer`). 2. Why do you want to use the same label (`MANUFACTURE_CAR`) for 2 different kinds of nodes (`CAR` and `BMW`)?

Comment: I use `MANUFACTURE_CAR` to distinguish between the bike Manufacturer. For `BIKE` I also use `MANUFACTURE_BIKE` as another label so that BWM can be differentiated for bikes and cars.

Comment: Sure, the `BMW` node represents a car manufacturer. But the `CAR` node represents (as far I understand your data model) just one specific instance of a car - and a car is obviously not a car manufacturer. So, why would you want the `MANUFACTURE_CAR` label for `CAR`? Also, what is the `MANUFACTURE` label supposed to represent?

Comment: Ok, my model was ambiguous and now I update the nodes and relations. So now I have `MANUFACTURER` and 2 type of them for CAR and BIKE. And also I made a reference to `CAR` instance for back tracing. Is this kind of labels are good to use?

Answer (score 0):

In the same way that you normalize data in a relational database, and you would not want to have to search and update one item in multiple tables, you do not want to have multiple labels for the same relationship.

It seems like you want to be able to search:

```
(:Company) -[:Manufactures]-> (:Car)
(:Company) -[:Manufactures]-> (:Bike)
```

That said, there is a good case for multiple labels when they code for different things, for example, when you want to search:

```
(:Animal) -[:Eats]-> (:Food)
(:Dog) -[:Eats]-> (:Food)
```